# Procv com aproximação no R

Tags: r

Eu tenho dois bancos de dados como os de baixo, o Dados1 possui apenas 6 observações enquanto Dados2 possui cerca de 5mil.

Dados1

| Valor | Faixa |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | <20 |
| 20 | 40 |
| 40 | 60 |
| 60 | 80 |
| 80 | 100 |
| 100 | >100 |

Dados2

| Valor |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 18 |
| 95 |
| 100 |
| 45 |
| 27 |

Eu gostaria de  criar uma nova coluna no Dados2 com o nível de cada valor consultando o Dados1. Como os números das duas colunas Valor podem ser diferentes, devo utilizar o de valor mais próximo.
Vi uma resolução criando essa função e um loop, mas não funcionou para mim:

```
procura <- function(x, y){
  return(which.min(abs(x-y)))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A maneira mais fácil é com `cut`. E é rápido, com uma tabela de 5000 linhas é quase instantâneo.

```r
cut_points <- c(Dados1$Valor, Inf)
cut(Dados2$Valor, breaks = cut_points, labels = Dados1$Faixa)
#> [1] <20 <20 100 100 60  40 
#> Levels: <20 40 60 80 100 >100

Dados2$Faixa <- cut(Dados2$Valor, breaks = cut_points, labels = Dados1$Faixa)
Dados2
#>   Valor Faixa
#> 1     5   <20
#> 2    18   <20
#> 3    95   100
#> 4   100   100
#> 5    45    60
#> 6    27    40
```

---

## Dados

```r
Dados1 <- read.table(
  text = "Valor     Faixa
0   <20
20  40
40  60
60  80
80  100
100     >100",
header = TRUE)
Dados2 <- read.table(
  text = "Valor
5
18
95
100
45
27",
header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Funcionou em partes! Entretanto as observações com valores exatos não retornam a faixa correta. Por exemplo, se te um valor 40, retorna a faixa 40 mas deveria retornar como faixa 60. Sabe como resolver?

Comment: @SunnySmith A função `cut` tem argumentos `include.lowest` e `right`. Tente várias combinações desses argumentos para ver qual é a melhor para o problema.